# cakephp 2.0 sorting on the fly

Tags: cakephp-2.0

so i have a search being paginated and presented to the end user just fine. I want to give the user a sort option via a select box ie:

```
by cheapest desc
by cheapest asc
by newest desc
by newest asc
```

but im unable to find any help on the cakephp website which would help with this.

is anyone able to advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create the default ORDER right. Then if you use Cake Views then the sorting options are default for any column. To sort it by default as cheapest DESC - use the following code:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'order'     => array('cheapest' => 'DESC')
);
$this->set('yourData', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```

to make the order Dynamic, post or get the select box data and set the filed and the order in 2 variables and set that like following:

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['ModelName']['fieldChoosen']) {
    $field = $this->request->data['ModelName']['fieldChoosen'];
    $order = $this->request->data['ModelName']['orderChoosen'];
} else {
    $field = 'cheapest';
    $order = 'DESC'
}

$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'order'     => array($field => $order)
);
$this->set('yourData', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```

Comment: Please up vote this as this is the best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

in the end i wrote a jQuery routine which solved my issue

```
    $('#paginationorder').on('change', function(){
    //get new sort instructions
    var temp = $(this).val();
    var temp = temp.split('.');
    var col = temp[0];
    var ord = temp[1];

    //check that you have new instructions then get and edit url
    if(col.length >0 && ord.length >0){
        var url = window.location.href;

        //establish if sort: is in url
        if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf('sort') >=0){
            var start = url.toLowerCase().indexOf('sort');
            var end = url.toLowerCase().indexOf('?');

            //assemble new string
            var sort = url.substring(0,start)+'sort:Properties.'+col+'/direction:'+ord+url.substring(end,url.length);
            $(location).attr('href',sort);
        }else{
            var start = url.toLowerCase().indexOf('?');

            var sort = url.substring(0,start)+'/sort:Properties.'+col+'/direction:'+ord+'?'+url.substring(start+1,url.length);
            $(location).attr('href',sort);
        }
    }else{
        alert('Oops, something went wrong, we have been unable to change the sort order. please try again');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question was for CakePHP. the answer I gave does it all and it is lot easier to sort it in CakePHP as that will give you the data from the table records. if you want to get records without refresh, use angular or ajax call to get the data